# How can i add a custom search to chrome when the URL doesn't change?

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines

how can i add a custom search to chrome when the address doesn't change? I want to have a custom search of a site, https://www.mixcloud.com/, what do I put as the URL?

Comment: https://www.mixcloud.com/search/results/?mixcloud_query=%s   I got this by running a search and replacing the query with %s

Comment: In the URL bar You can also type your keywords then site:https://www.mixcloud.com/

Answer (score -1):

Go to:  chrome://settings/ and "Manage Search Engines" button.

When you go to the bottom of the list you can add your mixcloud address.

[Set your search engine](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?p=settings_omnibox&rd=1)

Comment: mixcloud is not a search engine. mt025 has the right idea to search that site with keywords, and yes it could be set as a default search engine with the syntax he posted, you are partially correct.